# libjpeg gives poor quality image

Tags: image-processing, compression, jpeg, libjpeg

I'm using libjpeg to produce jpeg from raw RGB data at work. It works correctly, though the quality of the jpeg output is not satisfactory, and differences from similarly saved png (libpng) are significant. I thought, may be the default quality setting is set to low, but I checked that the default is set to 100, which is the maximum you can get for that library. Even setting that explicitly to 100 using jpeg_set_quality() didn't help. I then looked in the library description, and changed the default J_DCT_METHOD from JDCT_ISLOW to JDCT_FLOAT, just because it says the latter is a little more accurate than the former. The final output however is no different, and the image is still 'blurry' at places. I also checked that 'smoothing' is set to zero which could have made a difference if non-zero. If I didn't care about speed/memory, are there any other settings I can change to increase the fidelity of my image produced? I'm referencing this page for library methods : https://www4.cs.fau.de/Services/Doc/graphics/doc/jpeg/libjpeg.html

Thanks!

Comment: How about showing the blurry JPEG and the proper PNG so we can see the differences and deduce what's up?

Comment: I had thought of doing that, but currently I didn't have a file which is not customer data - which according to the privacy clause I can't share. I will try to produce something of my own and share soon.

Answer (score 0):

Poor JPEG quality comes from a combination of subsampling and quantization tables. In LibJpeg, the "quality" setting affects the latter. If you have set that to 100 and are still getting bad output, check the subsampling.

Also, JPEG is sensitive to the type of image. JPEG does not do a good job with images that consist of areas of the identical color (e.g., drawing, cartoons—as opposed to photographs)

Changing the DCT method, as you have suggested, will do little for the quality.